# Writing to Mysql database with X-editable and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a little db for my small office. I'm using x-editable plugin for bootstrap to edit live my fields and I cannot find where is the error, everything seems to work correctly except the part updating the database. I've left out the query part before the table, which is not important here, since the results are all correctly shown in the table.

This is the Table

```
echo'<tr class="'.$class.'">
                        <td class="xedit" id="id-'.$fetch['id'].'" data-pk="'.$fetch['id'].'"data-name="id">'.$fetch['id'].'</td>                       
                        <td class="xedit" id="status-'.$fetch['id'].'"data-pk="'.$fetch['id'].'"data-name="status">'.$status_output.'</td>  
                        <td class="xedit" id="pc-'.$fetch['id'].'" data-pk="'.$fetch['id'].'" data-name="pc">'.$fetch['pc'].'</td>
                        <td class="xedit" id="nome-'.$fetch['id'].'"data-pk="'.$fetch['id'].'" data-name="nome">'.$fetch['nome'].'</td>
                        <td class="xedit" id="cognome-'.$fetch['id'].'"data-pk="'.$fetch['id'].'"data-name="cognome">'.$fetch['cognome'].'</td>
                        <td class="xedit" id="email_new-'.$fetch['id'].'"data-pk="'.$fetch['id'].'"data-name="email_new">'.$fetch['email_new'].'</td>
                        <td class="xedit" id="email_pwd-'.$fetch['id'].'"data-pk="'.$fetch['id'].'"data-name="email_pwd">'.$fetch['email_pwd'].'</td>
                        <td class="xedit" id="interno-'.$fetch['id'].'"data-pk="'.$fetch['id'].'"data-name="interno">'.$fetch['interno'].'</td>
                        <td class="xedit" id="ip-'.$fetch['id'].'"data-pk="'.$fetch['id'].'"data-name="ip">'.$fetch['ip'].'</td>
                        <td class="xedit" id="ip_vpn-'.$fetch['id'].'"data-pk="'.$fetch['id'].'"data-name="ip_vpn">'.$fetch['ip_vpn'].'</td>
                        <td class="xedit" id="dc_user-'.$fetch['id'].'"data-pk="'.$fetch['id'].'"data-name="dc_user">'.$fetch['dc_user'].'</td>
                        <td class="xedit" id="dc_pwd-'.$fetch['id'].'"data-pk="'.$fetch['id'].'"data-name="dc_pwd">'.$fetch['dc_pwd'].'</td>
                        <td class="xedit" id="utenti_notes-'.$fetch['id'].'" data-pk="'.$fetch['id'].'"data-name="utenti_notes">'.$fetch['utenti_notes'].'</td>
                        <td><a href="delete.php?del=<?php echo $user_id ?>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></a></td>

                        </tr>';
```

This is the javascript code for x-editable

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
$('.xedit').editable({ 
url: 'server_processing.php',
success: function(response, newValue) {
        $('#' + response.name + '-' + response.pk).editable('setValue',newValue);
    }

});
```

});

And this is the server_processing.php page, it seems correct to me, but database is not being updated. Once the page is reloaded the submitted value disappear.

```
    <?php
include("connect.php");
$pk = $_POST['pk'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$value = $_POST['value'];
if ( mysql_query("update utenti set $name='$value' where id='$pk'") ) {
    print_r($_POST);
}
?>
```

Really thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: a) you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) b) you have absolutely **NO** error handling and are simply ASSUMING nothing could ever go wrong with your queries.;

Comment: a)It's a db on a local machine in a closed vlan, no problem about that, but I'll study deeper in this issue. b) The query is as simple as $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users);  Anyway I've solved the problem thanks anyway.